# Brief knowledge on PLC

Tags: automation, plc, scada

Can some one suggest me some elements to know briefly about Programmable Logic Controller?? I wanna know also about SCADA system. i have been trying to know but can not gather all those knowledge briefly.

Comment: Your question is too generic. What do you need to know exactly? For general informations, wikipedia page is available https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmable_logic_controller

Answer (score 1):

A PLC is a device designed to control a process.  Typically the PLC is directly on a machine.  SCADA (Supervisory Control and Data Acquisition) is a supervisory program installed on a PC that is collecting process data and displaying it for an overview of a plant or process.